# ScrollView gradient Textview getting overlapping on neighbor view when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, scrollview, gradient

I am just creating message reading information in one layout, I have the below layout xml file which have scrollview with Textviews(this textview have gradient colors which i am creating dynamically in java) on linear layout of vertical scrollview which is proper before keyboard pops up. When I click EditText view then keyboard popsup and all textview gets overlapping with each other. I tried all options like  android:windowSoftInputMode and android:fitsSystemWindows="true" again and again same result.

My layout xmlfile

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.talkeasy.messageperformancw.MainActivity" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xmlid_l_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Before Keybord pops up:**

[image]

**After Keyboard pops up**

[image]

If you see second image when keyboard popsup then views inside scrollview getting collapsing on each other,I don't want to use any layout_weight option and I want this issue get resolved :( . Stackoverflow is the only solution for me at last hope.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `linear.invalidate();` or `linear.requestLayout();` after the keyboard has already showed. I think your problem is that views didn't recalculate their size in layout.

Actually I think you can use 9.patch resource for background in TextView and set margins to them. I think it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried both linear.invalidate(); or linear.requestLayout(); still its not recalculating its size. I dont understand your second statement to use path 9 can please brief about how to use that patch , Thanks in advance

Comment: @ela0250 Here you can read about 9.patch: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
Maybe layouts draw better with it.